# What is the difference between CurrentValue and Value properties inside the Blazor's InputBase<T>?

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0

Looking at Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputbase-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) it states the following:

**CurrentValue** -> Gets or sets the current value of the input.

**Value** -> Gets or sets the value of the input. This should be used with two-way binding.

That doesn't tell me much. Is there a reason these properties are defined separately and if so why? Do they always contain the same value regardless of the component lifecycle stage? If so why have 2 different properties at all? In various examples on the Internet I've seen people declare binding with both properties. What am I missing?

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Forms/InputBase.cs,d8f66b0bacc9dac1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason these properties are defined separately and if so why?

Yes, `Value` is a public `Parameter` which means Blazor code will maintain its value - setting it whenever it is rendered. Code inside the component *should* not set this value directly (although it does) but, instead, should `Invoke` the `ValueChanged` EventCallback. This is handled in `InputBase` through the `CurrentValue` and `CurrentValueAsString` properties.

> Do they always contain the same value regardless of the component lifecycle stage?

`CurrentValue` doesn't "contain" a value - the `getter` returns `Value` though, so if you are reading them, they are referencing the same value.

> why have 2 different properties at all?

See answer 1 - `public` `Parameters` are maintained by the Blazor internal code, and should not be modified directly. But in reality, they break that rule here anyway, so the real reason is so they can call other code when the value of the input changes - in the `setter`s of `CurrentValueAsString` (parsing) and `CurrentValue` (validation)

> In various examples on the Internet I've seen people declare binding with both properties. What am I missing?

User code should only `@bind` to the public `Value` (`@bind-Value`) of an `Input???` component.

If you are implementing a new `InputFoo` component that inherits `InputBase`, then your code should use `CurrentValue`/`CurrentValueAsString` to bind to DOM elements.

Comment: ` so the real reason is so they can call other code when the value of the input changes.` But you emphatically say that `Code inside the component should not set this value directly (although it does)...` If that is the case, why not modify the components' state from within custom components ? What's the difference. I'll tell you what's the difference: At the begining, all the samples in the docs  were having code in which a component could modify its state. That was the way we did it.

Comment: But later on, some real issues had been discovered so that it was made clear by the creator of Blazor that component parameter properties should always be automatic. Incidentally, it was you from whom I've learned this (thank you). I was following the docs then, and they used code that was modifying the components' state. I guess that the reason why the InputBase component does modify its value is because it was too late to change the design of Blazor. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd be guessing, but my guess is they set Value because they are invoking `EditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier)` which is synchronous and will read the `Value` - if they don't set it first then validation could happen on the wrong value.

Comment: @Both.   I don't think `NotifyFieldChanged` cares about the value.   I think they either missed it after making the (right) decision about changing Parameters, or decided against creating another `xxxvalue` field.

Comment: Possibly correct.